# Reset Dropdown value before Submit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have two dropdown list and both are selected with values and when i want to change the first dropdown i want to reset the second before submit, but it doesn't works. He sends every time on post the second value who was selected before. I have no submit button, it is submitted on change on dropdown
Here's my code :

```js
    function reset() {
        $('#second').val("");
    }
```

```html
<!-- First Dropdown -->
    <select class="form-select mb-3" id="first" name="first" onsubmit="this.form.reset();" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1" >Hello</option>
        <option value="2" >World</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Second Dropdown -->
    <select class="form-select mb-3" id="second" name="second" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1" >Hello</option>
        <option value="2" >World</option>
    </select>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: `onsubmit` does nothing on a `select` element, that event fires for `form` elements only. And you can not just reset your complete form - that would reset the first select as well.

Comment: Hello CBroe, even when if i use onclick="reset();" it doesn't works. He send the second value who was selected before.

Comment: Don't name a custom function `reset`, that is likely to collide with the `reset` method of the form.

Comment: And you should do this in a change handler on the select element, and not a click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#first, #second').on('change', e =>{

  if($(e.target).is('#first')){
    $('#second').val('');
  }
  
  e.target.form.submit();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- First Dropdown -->
<form>
  <select class="form-select mb-3" id="first" name="first">
      <option value="1" >Hello</option>
      <option value="2" >World</option>
  </select>

  <!-- Second Dropdown -->
  <select class="form-select mb-3" id="second" name="second">
      <option value="1" >Hello</option>
      <option value="2" >World</option>
  </select>
</form>
```